# How do I render a word in the middle of the screen using FreeType and OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, c++, text

I'm following [this tutorial series](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/2D-Game/Breakout) on making a simple 2D clone of the classic Breakout game, but its author doesn't mention how to render **a whole word** or sentence in the middle of the screen. He simply uses hard-coded X and Y coordinates that obviously work for his screen, but not for mine (hence why the mere suggestion of using hard-coded values for something like this makes my skin crawl).

For more details on how he accomplishes the task, see [this page](https://learnopengl.com/In-Practice/2D-Game/Render-text) of the aforementioned tutorial.

My version of his game has two major differences:

1. I am rendering the GLFW window in fullscreen mode instead of a 800x600 window.
2. I suspect that even if I were to use a 800x600 window, things still wouldn't look consistent across every device. As such I have made many changes to hard-coded values across the entire code base.

I'm a perfectionist so even though no-one else will probably ever run my game, I'm trying to eliminate the possibility of different results on different resolutions. But to do that has turned out to be a massive undertaking!

Here is the code that I'm having particular trouble with:

```
void TextRenderer::RenderText(string text, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat scale, vec3 color) {
    // Activate corresponding render state  
    shader.Use();
    shader.SetVector3f("textColor", color);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    // Iterate through all characters
    for (auto c = text.begin(); c != text.end(); c++) {
        auto ch = characters[*c];

        auto xPos = x + ch.bearing.x * scale;
        auto yPos = y + (characters['H'].bearing.
            y - ch.bearing.y) * scale;
        auto w = ch.size.x * scale;
        auto h = ch.size.y * scale;

        // Update VBO for each character
        GLfloat vertices[6][4] = {
            { xPos,     yPos + h, 0.0, 1.0 },
            { xPos + w, yPos,     1.0, 0.0 },
            { xPos,     yPos,     0.0, 0.0 },

            { xPos,     yPos + h, 0.0, 1.0 },
            { xPos + w, yPos + h, 1.0, 1.0 },
            { xPos + w, yPos,     1.0, 0.0 }
        };

        // Render glyph texture over quad
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ch.textureID);

        // Update content of VBO memory
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0,
            sizeof(vertices), vertices);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        // Render quad and advance cursors for next glyph
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        // Bitshift by 6 to get value in pixels (1/64th times 2^6 = 64)
        x += (ch.advance >> 6) * scale;
    }

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

I have tried adding a `bool centreX` and `bool centreY` param to the function, as well as another `for` loop before the main one like this:

```
if (centreX || centreY) {
    auto textWidth = 0.0f;
    auto textHeight = 0.0f;

    for (auto c = text.begin(); c != text.end(); c++) {
        auto ch = characters[*c];

        if (centreX) {
            textWidth += (ch.bearing.x * scale) + (ch.size.
                x * scale) + ((ch.advance >> 6) * scale);
        }

        if (centreY) {
            textHeight += (y + (characters['H'].bearing.y -
                ch.bearing.y) * scale) + (ch.size.y * scale);
        }
    }

    if (centreX) {
        auto lastCh = text.end() - 1;
        textWidth -= (characters[*lastCh].advance >> 6) * scale;
    }
}
```

But for the sentence, font and font size used I'm getting a `textWidth` value of 1952 while a screenshot of the rendered text is 1143 px wide :S

Where has my math or understanding of the original code gone wrong? My display is a high DPI one and I have my Windows scaling settings at 200%; could either of those things be the culprit?

MTIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture below (from the website you linked) is quite good to understand what is going on. `Advance` is the distance from one character's origin to the next. To get the width of the whole text you should add the `advances` together. Right now you are adding the bearing, the width and the advance.

[image]

Once you have the size of your text and the size of your window you can add an offset to each character that is `(window_width - text_width)/2`.

Comment: OMG I feel like such a fool! I knew the last part, and that all I needed was the width...but for some stupid reason I was thinking 'advance' is the distance from the right side (i.e. perceived advance = actual advance - width - bearing). Moral of the story: when it's 4 am and you're yawning your head off, GO TO BED lol. Anyway thank you for your help :-)